# SQL to join/combine two similiar tables but incomplete into one more complete table

Tags: mysql, sql

Perhaps it's too complicated to write the problem so I will give you all the picture on how I want the final table looks like:

[image]

As you can see there are 3 tables,
1st and 2nd table are similar (have username and email)
but unfortunately not all username have email
but at least I can fix some username
and be able to join all the username without email in one table (like in 3rd table)
How can I do this in sql or using query?
I tried UNION but it repeat the "a" and "b".

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: oh sorry, i want to create the 3rd tables using the 1st and 2nd table.
The question is how can i do that in sql? i tried using UNION but it show duplicate a and b.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the results you're looking for:

```
Select      Coalesce(A.UserName, B.UserName) As UserName,
            Coalesce(A.Email, B.Email) As Email
From        TableA  A
Left Join   TableB  B   On  B.UserName = A.UserName
Union
Select      Coalesce(A.UserName, B.UserName) As UserName,
            Coalesce(A.Email, B.Email) As Email
From        TableA  A
Right Join  TableB  B   On  B.UserName = A.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided username is unique in both tables, you need FULL JOIN them. And as MySql has no FULL JOIN, you need to mimic it, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101549/how-to-mimic-a-full-outer-join-using-mysql-views